# This program reads in integers until a sentinel number is read. And prints the largest integer read

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm just looking for feedback on how I could improve this simple program. Whether it be comments for better understanding or better variable names. I try not to focus on memory consumption because I'm honestly not that knowledgeable as of yet. My main focus is getting a written solution on paper and then implement in syntax.

I was given the question to write a program that reads in integers one per line, once a sentinel integer is read end program, and display the largest integer. The way I solved it was with pen and paper first because I'm working on my pseudocode and algorithm design. If there are any books on the subject for recommendation. I would greatly appreciate.

```
/**
 * This program reads in integers until a sentinel number is read, 
 * and prints the largest. 
 *
 * @author shawn
 *
 */

//Import needed for Console Programs.
import acm.program.*;

public class LargestListValue extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {

        /*Integer variables to track the current largest input 
         * and current input.
         */
        int x, y;

        println("This program reads in integers until a sentinel number is read, ");
        println("and prints the largest.");


        while (true) { //Initial while to read in an initial integer.
            x = readInt(" ? "); //Initial read integer. Also current largest.
            if (x == SENTINEL_NUMBER) { 
                println("No numbers?");
                break;
            }
            else {
                y = readInt(" ? "); //Next read integer.
                if (y == SENTINEL_NUMBER) {
                    println("Largest number is " + x + ".");
                    break;
                } else {
                    while (y <= x) { //While second read integer
                        y = readInt(" ? ");
                        if (y == SENTINEL_NUMBER) {
                            println("Largest number is " + x + ".");
                            break;
                        } else if (y >= x) {
                            while (y >= x) {
                                x = readInt(" ? ");
                                if (x == SENTINEL_NUMBER) {
                                    println("Largest number is " + y + ".");
                                    break;
                                } else if (y <= x) break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Extra break added to the
            break;
        }
    }
    //Sentinel number to end reading integers and print largest.
    private static final int SENTINEL_NUMBER = 0;
}
```

Comment: Some of the comments are incomplete btw. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>                 break;
>             }
>             else {
> ```

You don't need an `else` with a `break`.  The `break` ends execution inside the loop.  You can never reach the code after it in the loop unless it doesn't trigger.  Without all the `else` clauses, you can significantly reduce the amount of indentation.

Your code could also `return` instead of `break`.  That would be clearer in my opinion.

What's `x`?  What's `y`?  Why loop forever if you're just going to `break` out of it?

In my opinion, your comments would be better replaced with more readable, self-commenting code.

Consider the following

```
    public static int readLargest(final int SENTINEL) {
        int largest = readInt(" ? ");
        for (int current = largest; current != SENTINEL; current = readInt(" ? ") ) {
            if (current > largest) {
                largest = current;
            }
        }

        return largest;
    }
```

Which you'd use as

```
    public void run() {
        int largest = readLargest(SENTINEL_NUMBER);

        if (largest == SENTINEL_NUMBER) {
            println("No numbers?");
        } else {
            println("Largest number is " + largest + ".");
        }
    }
```

By using a separate method, we consolidate the possibilities.  We only have two `println` statements.  In the original code, you had the latter option three times.  Here we only need one.

This also makes the `readLargest` more reusable.  Even better might be to read all the values first, then call a `findLargest` method on that.  Then your `readNumbers` and `findLargest` methods would both be reusable separately.  Of course, you may not have gotten to `Collection` types yet.

In your original code, sometimes `y` was the largest and sometimes `x`.  In this code, `largest` is always the largest unless the most recent read returns a larger value.

I prefer the names `current` and `largest` as being more descriptive than single letter names.  I find that more important with `largest`.  I could live with `x` instead of `current`.

I'm not sure that it's necessary to say `SENTINEL_NUMBER`.  The `current` variable is an integer.  What would `SENTINEL` be?  A cabbage?  Obviously not.  You'd only compare an integer to some kind of number.  Others may disagree.  In particular, you may want to look up [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

I prefer to pass the sentinel value as a parameter for flexibility.

Since we don't use `current` outside of the loop, I think that the `for` loop has better scope than a while loop.

The only comment that seems necessary is that `readLargest` will return the sentinel value if and only if there are no other numbers in the input (prior to the sentinel value).  Other than that, I feel that the code is pretty clear about what it is doing.  Perhaps some explanation of the initialization of `largest`.

Comment: I agree with the your points. I'm only 4 chapters deep into "The Art and Science of Java, by Eric. R".  Using `return` would be best. I know a little JavaScript and I was thinking the same thing. Thank you so much. Every word is greatly appreciated. As I read more on the language, I will refer to this post and implement these ideas.